# How do I process multiple forms generated dynamically with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, vuejs2

I am dynamically generating an HTML form with Vue. There is a *New Employee* button which, when clicked, appends a new form together with it's submit button to the page. The submit button calls a method which makes the field in the form read only. However when I click on any of the submit buttons it affects all the forms in the page. I want each button to be responsible for only it's own form. How do I achieve this?

This is my HTML page:

```
<!-- Index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Form</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"> 
</script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container" id="app">
 <button class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top: 15px;"
 @click="addNewEmployeeForm"
>
    New Employee
 </button>

 <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-bottom: 13px;">
    <div class="panel-body" v-for="(employee, index) in employees">

        <span class="pull-right" style="cursor: pointer;" @click="deleteEmployeeForm(index)">X</span>

        <h4>Add Employee (index: {{ index }} )</h4>

        <div class="employee-form">

            <form id="e-form" @submit.prevent="processForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" v-model="employee.name" :readonly="readonly == 1 ? true : false">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputJob">Job</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Job" v-model="employee.job" :readonly="readonly == 1 ? true : false">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputAbout">About</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="About" v-model="employee.about" :readonly="readonly == 1 ? true : false"></textarea>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my JS file:

```
// Main.js
window.onload = function () {

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {

        readonly: 0,
        employees: [
        {
            name: '',
            job: '',
            about: ''
        }
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        addNewEmployeeForm() {
            this.employees.push({
                name: '',
                job: '',
                about: ''
            })
        },
        deleteEmployeeForm( index ) {
            this.employees.splice(index, 1);
        },
        processForm: function() {
            this.readonly = (this.readonly + 1) % 2;
            //console.log({ name: this.employees[0].name, job: this.employees[0].job, about: this.employees[0].about });

        }
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your employee object to the `processForm` method, and store the readonly flag per employee:

```
<form id="e-form" @submit.prevent="processForm(employee)">
....
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" v-model="employee.name" :readonly="employee.readOnly == 1 ? true : false">

...                


data: {
    employees: [
    {
        name: '',
        job: '',
        about: '',
        readOnly: false,
    }
    ]
},
addNewEmployeeForm() {
    this.employees.push({
        name: '',
        job: '',
        about: '',
        readOnly: false,
    })
},
processForm: function(employee) {
    employee.readonly = !employee.readonly;
    console.log({ name: employee.name, job: employee.job, about: employee.about });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this but it is not working. The forms do not become read only upon clicking submit on any of the forms

Comment: I see I made an capitalization typo in `readOnly`, can you confirm it is written like `readOnly ` in the html?

Comment: I fixed the capitalization. I also removed ```readonly``` from the employees array and instead put it directly in the data object. I did a similar thing with the addNewEmployeeForm() method. It kind of works but in an unexpected way. Upon clicking the submit button, the fields are not disabled but if i move my cursor to any of the fields and type something it suddenly gets disabled.

Comment: You need the readonly in the employee array, as you want to make it readonly per employee, not everythin at once